# Android Support Toolbar Styling

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement a Light Theme of AppCompat with a dark toolbar (action bar), however when adding the toolbar dynamically or using `<include />` the text fails to display in the correct color (black instead of white). The default action bar is styled correctly, but when I add the toolbar it is not.

Here is my code:

`toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    />
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ff299725</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff1d691b</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff5fb10b</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

However I get this in preview and live environment:

[image]

I have tried different versions of AppCompat (v.22.1, v.22.2, v.21.0.3) all replicate the issue, I have tried adding extra styles for `textColor` and all that happens is that it styles everything white.

Any help SO legends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your toolbar.xml, remove the `app:theme` attribute and use this instead:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Also, depending on how you're implementing toolbar, you may want to change your base theme (in styles.xml) to use the `NoActionBar` variant, like so:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/xxx</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/xxx</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/xxx</item>
    <item name="gapBetweenBars">4dp</item>
</style>
```

`my_toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
    />
```